# Fill area between multiple lines in plot

Tags: r, plot, lines, fill, area

I have got a plot with 3 lines as follows:

```
a = data.frame(time = c(1:100), x = rnorm(100))
b = data.frame(time = c(1:100), y = rnorm(100))
c = data.frame(time = c(1:100), z = rnorm(100))

plot(a$time, a$x, type = 'l')
lines(b$time, b$y, type = 'l')
lines(c$time, c$z, type = 'l')
```

I need to fill the area between the lowest and maximum value of the lines so that I get a unique polygon of a given colour.

I know about the `polygon` function but I do not know how to use it in this case.

Any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean with 'to fill the area between the lowest and maximum value of the lines'? Should the area below the line be filled until the minimum value of the line be filled? Or should the area between 0 and the line be filled? Or ...?

Comment: Simply try `polygon(c(b$time, rev(c$time)), c(b$y, rev(c$z)),col = "gray", border = "red")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach:

```
a = data.frame(time = c(1:100), x = rnorm(100))
b = data.frame(time = c(1:100), y = rnorm(100))
c = data.frame(time = c(1:100), z = rnorm(100))
```

calculate the `pmin` and `pmax`:

```
min_a <- pmin(a, b, c)
max_a <- pmax(a, b, c)
```

construct the polygon as usual:

```
polygon(c(c$time, rev(c$time)), c(max_a$x ,rev(min_a$x)), col = rgb(1, 0, 0,0.5) )
```

[image]

or using ggplot:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(a, b, c) %>% #combine the three data frames
  group_by(time) %>% # group by time for next step
  mutate(max = max(x, y, z), # calculate max of x, y, z in each time
         min = min(x, y, z)) %>% #same as above
  select(-time.1, - time.2) %>% #discard redundant columns
  gather(key, value, 2:4) %>% #convert to long format so you can color by key in the geom line call
  ggplot()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = time, ymin= min, ymax = max), fill= "red", alpha = 0.3)+
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = value, color = key))
```

[image]