# Shade in R using ggplot2 in R when given a range

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code

```
p <- ggplot(data = Speed_results,
            aes(x = ln_sample_size, y = max_speed, group = func, colour = func)) +
  # blue plot
  #geom_point(data=Speed_results, aes(x=ln_sample_size, y=max_speed), colour="darkblue", size=1) + 
  geom_line(data=Speed_results, aes(x=ln_sample_size, y=max_speed), size=1, linetype = "dashed") + 

  geom_point(data=Speed_results, aes(x=ln_sample_size, y=median_speed),  size=1) + 
  geom_line(data=Speed_results, aes(x=ln_sample_size, y=median_speed),  size=1) + 

  geom_point(data=Speed_results, aes(x=ln_sample_size, y=min_speed), size=1) + 
  geom_line(data=Speed_results, aes(x=ln_sample_size, y=min_speed),  size=1, linetype = "dashed") + 

  # red plot
  geom_point(data=Speed_results, aes(x=ln_sample_size, y=max_speed),  size=1) + 
  geom_line(data=Speed_results, aes(x=ln_sample_size, y=max_speed),  size=1, linetype = "dashed") + 

  geom_point(data=Speed_results, aes(x=ln_sample_size, y=median_speed), size=1) + 
  geom_line(data=Speed_results, aes(x=ln_sample_size, y=median_speed),  size=1) + 

  geom_point(data=Speed_results, aes(x=ln_sample_size, y=min_speed),  size=1) +
  geom_line(data=Speed_results, aes(x=ln_sample_size, y=min_speed), size=1, linetype = "dashed") +
```

I want to plot y_minimum, y_maximum with the points connected by lines on the same graph for corresponding x values and shade from y_minimum to y_maximum range using ggplot2 feature in R. 
Here's the [graph with dummy values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNNOX.png) . Need to shade between pink dashed lines. Need to again shade between the blue dashed lines. Please help. Thanks.

My data frame looks alike:

```
>Speed_results
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   func   ln_sample_size max_speed median_speed min_speed
   <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 group1              2      7.01         6.8       6.61
 2 group2              2     11.4          8.93      8.24
 3 group1              3      9.86         8.60      8.4 
 4 group2              3     16.6         12.8      11.9 
 5 group1              4     28.3         26.5      26.1 
 6 group2              4     53.6         46.3      45.2 
 7 group1              5      6.47         6.45      6.45
 8 group2              5      6.89         6.68      6.65
 9 group1              6      8.48         8.25      8.23
10 group2              6     30.6         13.0      12.5 
11 group1              7     27.6         26.2      26.1 
12 group2              7    110.          86.1      78.1 

> dput(Speed_results)
structure(list(func = c("group1", "group2", "group1", "group2", 
"group1", "group2", "group1", "group2", "group1", "group2", "group1", 
"group2"), ln_sample_size = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 
7), max_speed = c(7.00625, 11.375, 9.8625, 16.5875, 28.26875, 
53.6125, 6.46558125, 6.88586875, 8.47971875, 30.60874375, 27.55455625, 
110.140775), median_speed = c(6.8, 8.934375, 8.603125, 12.80625, 
26.5, 46.334375, 6.45095625, 6.675790625, 8.25186875, 12.96550625, 
26.213890625, 86.12590625), min_speed = c(6.6125, 8.2375, 8.4, 
11.875, 26.1, 45.24375, 6.44804375, 6.653425, 8.23073125, 12.45396875, 
26.12114375, 78.09409375)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi Dovini Jayasinghe. Could you show us your attempt and the problem with it?

Comment: yes sure. Let me add the graph I have. What I need is to shade between red line and green line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill area between multiple lines in plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204985/fill-area-between-multiple-lines-in-plot)

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't find it earlier. What I came across was filling area under the curve.

Comment: partially yes. it did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code for that (taking help from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48205302/6123824)

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x, y_minimum,y_maximum) %>% #combine the three data frames
  group_by(x) %>% # group by x for next step
  mutate(max = max(y_minimum, y_maximum), # calculate max of y_minimum, y_maximum
         min = min(y_minimum, y_maximum)) %>% #calculate min of y_minimum, y_maximum
  gather(key, value, 2:3) %>% #convert to long format so you can color by key in the geom line call
  ggplot()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = min, ymax = max), fill= "red", alpha = 0.3)+
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = value, color = key))
```

[image]

## Update

Data

```
df = structure(list(func = c("group1", "group2", "group1", "group2", 
        "group1", "group2", "group1", "group2", "group1", "group2", "group1", 
        "group2"), ln_sample_size = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 
        7), max_speed = c(7.00625, 11.375, 9.8625, 16.5875, 28.26875, 
        53.6125, 6.46558125, 6.88586875, 8.47971875, 30.60874375, 27.55455625, 
        110.140775), median_speed = c(6.8, 8.934375, 8.603125, 12.80625, 
        26.5, 46.334375, 6.45095625, 6.675790625, 8.25186875, 12.96550625, 
        26.213890625, 86.12590625), min_speed = c(6.6125, 8.2375, 8.4, 
        11.875, 26.1, 45.24375, 6.44804375, 6.653425, 8.23073125, 12.45396875, 
        26.12114375, 78.09409375)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
        "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Plotting with `ggplot2`

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(y=median_speed, x=ln_sample_size, group=func, colour=func,
                          fill=func)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=min_speed, ymax=max_speed), alpha=.3, linetype=0) +
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "x label",
       y = "y label",
       title = "Title")
```

[image]

Comment: This helped me partially. I have 2 sets of these in the same plot. when I added geom_ribbon command with (say) red, and again that command with blue for the next 2 lines (altogether I have 4 lines - two red and two blue) all were shaded in red. how can I shade then in two different colors?

Comment: Without your data, it is impossible to help you. You can provide the data in `dput()` format.

Comment: My column names are,  ln_sample_size, min_speed, max_speed, median_speed, func. ln_sample_size is the X axis. func has two categories (say group 1 and group 2). Rest of the columns come as Y axis values.

Comment: In your answer provided, say the pink shade area represents group 1. I need to have another similar sort of shading area (say blue), for group 2 in the same graph.

Comment: Please see this link to see my data frame pattern. https://drive.google.com/file/d/19NpxgSeea0qunsRd_WWi3mW-g6p-rTJN/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Please edit your question by providing the data in `dput( )` format.

Comment: Is it okay if I put data by hand? Because this is a part of a research where I'm not supposed to out the data due to confidential issues.

Comment: You can create a fake data alike original data in place of original data and provide that.

Comment: Now see my update. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This really is what I expected. Exactly this. Thank you so so much.